# jQuery retains variable changes even though i don't explicitly return it when deferred are used

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, .when

In the function below, getNumber is executed. I am using item_list to store results of ajax calls. As you can see below i dont pass or item_list anywhere allthough after getNumber() finishes going though for loop, i am able console.log full output item_list.

I am interested how does item_list is able to retain everything that pushed into it by getNumberQuery().

```
function getNumber(id, def) {
 var item_list = [];
 var ajax_def_list = [];
 var proj = id.split(',');

 for (var pro_id = 0; pro < proj.length; pro_id++) {
    var ajax_def = $.Deferred();
    ajax_def_list.push(ajax_def);


    var url = api((endpoint('api')), '?search=' + proj[pro_id]);
    getNumberQuery(url, item_list, ajax_def);


   }
   $.when.apply($, ajax_def_list).then(function(status){
      console.log(id, item_list);
      def.resolve();
   });
}

function getNumberQuery(url, item_list, ajax_def){

 $.when($.ajax(url)).done(function (responce) {
        if (isValid(responce)) {

                    item_list.push(responce['item']);

                ajax_def.resolve();

        } else {
            console.log('Fail to get number : ' + responce);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there code missing at Question?

Comment: jQuery is doing nothing with the numbers - as you say, you're not passing them to jQuery. It's just the array `number` (misspelled: `numbers`) that holds them, like all arrays do.

Comment: That single deferred `d` - with `d_list.length === 1` always - makes the whole exercise futile. It only works out of sheer luck and bugs in jQuery promises.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the real code, not pseudo `for(x times)` code

Comment: I have updated the code to show current implementation